# Thread-safe version of mock.call_count

Tags: python, multithreading, unit-testing, mocking

It appears that [Mock.call_count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_count) does not work correctly with threads. For instance:

```
import threading
import time
from mock import MagicMock


def f():
    time.sleep(0.1)

def test_1():
    mock = MagicMock(side_effect=f)
    nb_threads = 100000
    threads = []
    for _ in range(nb_threads):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=mock)
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    assert mock.call_count == nb_threads, mock.call_count

test_1()
```

This code produced the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 24, in <module>
    test_1()
  File "test1.py", line 21, in test_1
    assert mock.call_count == nb_threads, mock.call_count
AssertionError: 99994
```

Is there a way I can use `call_count` (or similar) within a multithreaded portion of code? I'd like to avoid having to rewrite MagicMock myself...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally made it work by using a counter linked to the side effect method and a lock.

```
import threading
import time
from mock import MagicMock

lock_side_effect = threading.Lock()

def f():
    with lock_side_effect:
        f.call_count += 1
    time.sleep(0.1)

f.call_count = 0

def test_1():
    mock = MagicMock(side_effect=f)
    nb_threads = 100000
    threads = []
    for _ in range(nb_threads):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=mock)
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    assert f.call_count == nb_threads, f.call_count

test_1()
```

Consequently, I'm counting the number of calls of `f` instead of `mock`, but the result behaves as expected.

Comment: I spent hours trying to figure out why some of my tests were breaking randomly so I figured it was a race condition type of issues.  Ended up being the call_count not being set in multithreading programming.  I used your approached and now works like a charm.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little library that handles this.

It can be problematic to refactor a massive test suite, so this library allows you to patch the base class call to mocking `__getattr__` with an RLock.

https://github.com/AtakamaLLC/tsmock

You can do this:

```
from tsmock import MagicMock
```

Or this:

```
from tsmock import thread_safe_mocks
thread_safe_mocks()
```

Either one gets you the correct call count.